Use of multiple whereHas
I want to do two filters on my data:
Take all loans from a specific portfolio
Among these, only select those that expire within the deadline.
However, during the request, I realized that only the first one is being applied, even though I reversed it
public function getReceivableLoansByWalletId(string $walletId, int $days): Collection
    {
        $startDate = Carbon::today();
        $endDate = Carbon::today()->addDays($days);

        return Loan::whereHas('customer.wallet', function ($query) use ($walletId) {
                $query->where('id', $walletId);
            })
            ->whereHas('installments', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                $query->where('status', '==', 'EM DIAS')
                ->whereBetween('expectedDate', [$startDate, $endDate]);
            })
            ->with(['installments'])
            ->get();
    }


Get rid of the '==' parameter.

Apparently the error occurred because of the second where, you don't need the "=="

Know that SQL does not use == for a comparison, only a single =. To Laravel's where function, the second parameter could be a '=', but this will be used by default if only two parameters (a column and value pair) are provided.
